# GCP - Auto ML Table - "Import your data" from GCP BigQuery table fails with "contains 0 rows, must have at least 1000"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to use Google Cloud Platform (GCP) [Auto ML Table](https://console.cloud.google.com/automl-tables). The first step is to import my data from my GCP Big Query table.

When I try to do the import from the screen which says "Import your data", I get the following error (I have replaced my object names with j,x,y,z):

```
Failed to import data to data set jjjjjjjjjjj. The BigQuery table bq://xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzzzz contains 0 rows, must have at least 1000.
```

However, when I use GCP BigQuery to run a select query against that table I see I have over 1000 rows in that table.

I see the following requirements listed. I think my Big Query table satisfies them all:

```
For both import sources, your data must meet the following requirements:

Has between 1,000 and 100,000,000 rows
Has between 2 and 1,000 columns
Is 100 GB or less
```

Comment: Please check whether you meet the requirements https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare#preparing_your_import_source

Comment: My data satisfies the requirements listed in the question.

Comment: I just tried it a while ago and it worked with my BQ table with 19 columns and 79+million rows, means the service is working. Since AutoML Tables is still in beta then I would I suggest that you file this issue so this can be investigated --> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=625378

Comment: It seems to be working now. I have not changed anything either in the source table or the import. Perhaps there is some latency/delay with Big Query data being available. My Big Query data is tiny, only 1200 rows and about 20 columns. I saw something a little similar where I could not delete rows out of the Big Query table until a number of minutes after they were added.

Comment: Good for you mate. But it seems the error message does not represent the actual issue since it worked without any changes in your BQ table

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I raised an issue using that link.